# c# wpf datagrid row index

Tags: c#, wpf, datatables

I have tried several methods of returning a current row index value but all suggestions so far are not accepted as valid code in my environment. I would like to get an index value of the row in focus or through the row button I have inserted. Here is my test code -
xaml

```
<DataGrid x:Name="dataGrid1"  Loaded="WhenLoaded" AutoGenerateColumns="False" Margin="0,0,478,274" SelectionMode="Single" SelectionChanged="dataGrid1_SelectionChanged" >
    <DataGridTemplateColumn>
        <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Button Name="Select" Click="Row_Click" Content="Select" />
            </DataTemplate>
        </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
    </DataGridTemplateColumn>
    <DataGridTextColumn Header="node" Binding="{Binding Path=NODE}"   />
    <DataGridTextColumn Header="name" Binding="{Binding Path=NAME}"  />
    <DataGridTextColumn Header="s/n" Binding="{Binding Path=SERIAL_NO}"  />
</DataGrid.Columns>
```

C#

```
        myDataSet.Tables.Add(myTable);
        myDataSet.Tables.Add(myTable2);  

        myTable.Columns.Add("NODE", typeof(string));
        myTable.Columns.Add("NAME", typeof(string));
        myTable.Columns.Add("SERIAL_NO", typeof(string));

        myTable.Rows.Add(new string[] { "99", "Pressure", "1234" });

        dataGrid1.ItemsSource = myTable.DefaultView;
```

I have tried using this method to access the indexes but RowIndex and ColumnIndex are not recognised -

```
private void Row_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        int row = dataGrid1.CurrentCell.RowIndex;
        int col = dataGrid1.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `SelectedIndex` property:

```
    private void Row_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var selectedRowIndex = dataGrid1.SelectedIndex

    }
```

Alternatively, you can get row index from the current cell (a bit redundant though):

```
var row = (DataGridRow)dataGrid1.ItemContainerGenerator
          .ContainerFromItem(dataGrid1.CurrentCell.Item);
Console.WriteLine(row.GetIndex());
```

There is no column index on wpf `DataGridCell`, but you may get `DisplayIndex` instead (beware it may change when columns get rearranged)

```
Console.WriteLine(dataGrid1.CurrentCell.Column.DisplayIndex);
```

If you want to know which column/property in the data you're accessing, you will need to find it out based on something else than `DisplayIndex` (for example on `CurrentCell.Column.Header`)

If you want to get indexes without placing a button in your column, you can use for example `DataGrid.MouseUp` or `DataGrid.MouseLeftButtonUp` events.

You can find a more in-depth explanation [here](http://blog.scottlogic.com/2008/12/02/wpf-datagrid-detecting-clicked-cell-and-row.html).

Comment: Thank you, simple when you know how. SelectedIndex is just what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

```
private void Row_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
      DataRowView dataRow = (DataRowView)dataGrid1.SelectedItem;          
      string cellValue_Method1 = dataRow.Row.ItemArray[3].ToString();
      string cellValue_Method2 = dataRow[0].ToString();
      int index = dataGrid1.CurrentCell.Column.DisplayIndex;
      MessageBox.Show("index "+index + " cell value frist from method: "+cellValue_Method1 + " cell value from second method: "+cellValue_Method2);
}
```